# Не собирается flutter приложение в codemagic (IOS)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

Пытаюсь собрать IOS приложение на flutter при помощи [codemagic.io](http://codemagic.io) , но мне сборщик выдает такую ошибку:

```
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install
```

Как я понял, он ругается на зависимость firebase_core:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "firebase_core":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Для воспроизведения ошибки на практически пустом проекте, мне было достаточно добавить в pubspec.yaml 3 ключевые в моем проекте зависимости:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^3.0.0
  firebase_messaging: any
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dependency_overrides:
  # Override for `flutter_local_notifications`:
  plugin_platform_interface: ^2.0.0
```

Ссылка на проект: [test_on_firebase_core](https://github.com/Hnakra/test_on_firebase_core)

Настройки сборщика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы простое, хоть в коде и используется зависимость firebase_core,  в pubspec.yaml ее указывать не нужно, лишь те сервисы, которые вам нужны

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_local_notifications: ^3.0.0
  firebase_messaging: any
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```